# node.js grab data from array or object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I try to retrieve data only on the body object, and I am confused by this section

My code

```
      coin_price: async function(callback){
        var coingecko = await CoinGeckoClient.simple.price({
                ids: config.tickercoins,
                vs_currencies: ['usd', 'btc', 'idr', 'eur', 'jpy', 'krw'],
              });
            callback(null, coingecko);
      },
```

Result:

```
"coin_price": {
"success": true,
"message": "OK",
"code": 200,
"data": {
  "loki-network": {
    "usd": 0.202249,
    "btc": 0.000055,
    "idr": 2905.52,
    "eur": 0.176356,
    "jpy": 22.18,
    "krw": 225.42
     }}},
```

And I want to be like this:

```
    "coin_price": {
    "usd": 0.202249,
    "btc": 0.000055,
    "idr": 2905.52,
    "eur": 0.176356,
    "jpy": 22.18,
    "krw": 225.42
    },
```

And I tried to edit my code like:

```
      coin_price: async function(callback){
        var coingecko = await CoinGeckoClient.simple.price({
                ids: config.tickercoins,
                vs_currencies: ['usd', 'btc', 'idr', 'eur', 'jpy', 'krw'],
              });
            callback(null, coingecko.data);
      },
```

And result:

```
     "coin_price": {
       "loki-network": {
       "usd": 0.202249,
       "btc": 0.000055,
       "idr": 2905.52,
       "eur": 0.176356,
       "jpy": 22.18,
       "krw": 225.42
       }},
```

The code: `callback(null, coingecko.data[0]);` does not work

Is there an example so the results can be as I want?

Comment: `coingecko.data['loki-network']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `coingecko.data` object uses the key `"loki-network"`, not `0`. Adjust your callback so that it returns that property instead:

```
callback(null, coingecko.data["loki-network"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mark Meyer said in the comments, in order to get the json like you want you can do this:

```
//this is the resposne data
let json = {"coin_price": {
"success": true,
"message": "OK",
"code": 200,
"data": {
  "loki-network": {
    "usd": 0.202249,
    "btc": 0.000055,
    "idr": 2905.52,
    "eur": 0.176356,
    "jpy": 22.18,
    "krw": 225.42
     }}}}
let coin_price = json.coin_price.data["loki-network"] //this is where you access the data
console.log(coin_price)
```